# last row getting deleted. js jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Guys I have a var ad which stores all the ID'S from DB, and I am using that var ad as a parameter in post to delete the particular row from table in delete page. Right now when I clicked a button its only deleting the last row of a table. I did some debugging and find out that everytime I clicked a button its sending the ID of the last element, however I want to delete/send the ID of the row clicked.Please look below code for more info any help will be highly appreciated.

```js
function something() {
  for (var i = 0; i < (testvalues.length); i = i + 2) {
    //my logic 

    var ad = testvalues[i + 4]; //list of ID'S from DB[1,2,3....]

  }
  $(".sukuti").click(function() {

    //here im passing ad=id as a parameter
    $.post("delete.jsp", {
      id: ad
    }, function(data) { //everytime its sendind the ID of the row so last row is being deleted i need to delete the particular row which is being clciked.
      //this post goes to delete page which have query to delete
    });

  });
```

```html
<button class="sukuti" type="button">
```

Comment: You should bring the related part of the DOM here.

Comment: Didn't I answer a similar question earlier today?

Comment: You're overwriting the `ad` variable each time through the loop. At the end of the loop it contains the value from the last iteration.

Comment: You need to set the `ad` variable when they click on the thing they want to delete. You can't set it just once when the function is called.

Comment: Barmar thx for your answer earlier but it did not worked, I have been trying to solve this since 3 days , plss guide me

Comment: You can pass parameter in button click. Set button click parameter in button

Comment: You should have clarified the earlier question instead of posting a new question.

Comment: yes I agree barmar, I got rid of those checkboxes and right now I am  just using one button

Answer (score 0):

Well since you didn't show your real code let's create a scenario to help you.

```js
$(".sukuti").click(function(){
  var rowId = $(this).closest('tr').find('td.id').text();
  console.log("Id found:", rowId);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="id">10</td>
    <td><a href="javascript:;" class="sukuti">Remove</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="id">11</td>
    <td><a href="javascript:;" class="sukuti">Remove</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="id">12</td>
    <td><a href="javascript:;" class="sukuti">Remove</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="id">13</td>
    <td><a href="javascript:;" class="sukuti">Remove</a></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Ramon thx for your effort , but I am passing ID through post to run the query. I was trying to see if I can pass a particular ID based on button onclcik